# Angular2 No provider for service - external module

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I built an Angular `Module` that has it's own service and components:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ FileUploader],
  exports: [ FileUploader ],
  imports: [ CommonModule ],
  providers: [ FileService ],
})
export class FilesModule { }
```

And the `FileService`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class FileService
{
    constructor() {}

    uploadFile(file): Promise {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

then I import it to my `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  entryComponents: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [ FilesModule ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When I inject the `FileService` to the `AppComponent` I get an ERROR:

**Error in AppComponent: No Provider for FileService**

From Angular docs:

> When we import a module, Angular adds the module's service providers (the contents of its providers list) to the application root injector.
>
> This makes the provider visible to every class in the application that knows the provider's lookup token.

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: do you import FileService in your app.module.ts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you trying use FileService at AppComponent level. If you do that you should add FileService to AppModule's providers or using FileService at FileModule level.

Possibly, you forget about *@Injectable()* anotation in your FileService

Comment: I'm importing `FileService` at the `FileModule` level and I didn't forget the `@Injectable()`

Comment: This was it! I had a different file still importing the `FileService` from `AppModule` level - I wonder why I got **Error in AppComponent** and not in that file.

Answer (score 4):

I always create a `ForRoot` method when providers are in play in my `NgModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [FileUploader],
  exports: [FileUploader],
  imports: [CommonModule]
})
export class FilesModule {

  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: FilesModule,
      providers: [
        FileService
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can then use this in your `AppModule`:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent],
  imports: [FilesModule.forRoot()]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: I added the `forRoot` method, but still getting the error

Comment: and you added `forRoot()` inside your `AppModule` imports?

Comment: that's exactly what I did

Comment: I removed all dependencies and functionality from the service - nothing helped

Comment: It seems like you are trying to use something as a provider which cannot be a provider. Can you show how you defined your FileService?

Comment: I added the FileService to the question - thanks for your help!

Comment: I've created a working [**plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rCfiv5DZ3k54JaHEu79A?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts). Can you compare your version with this one? And see what could be wrong? Or create a plunkr yourself where you demonstrate the issue. Can it be that you are not using a proper IDE and it could be a difference between importing `FileService` vs `FilesService` in the import statement of AppComponent

Comment: I found it! see the comment in Jaroslaw K.'s answer. It worked without the `forRoot` - Thanks any ways.